# how to configure django form to create select option with query specific?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

how to configure django form to create select option with query specific.
Example1, i need create a select with user below a group but if i use just model i have every user, and just need the users specific.

Example2. i have this models:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

I Have this datas

[apple, red], [banana, yellow], [strammberry, red], [orange, orange]...

when i create my form i need select field that show me  fruits color red.
apple, strammberry.

but show me all fruit.    apple, banana, strammberry, orange

what is the form to  this do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) in your form, or if you want the choices to be determined by a query, then a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).